# How Add Custom Mail Merge Fields in Rich Text Editor in Devexpress Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, rich-text-editor, devexpress-mvc

I want to add Mail Merge fields in Rich Text Editor programmatically.

I have % fields like Name, Address, Gender, City, Phone No, DOB.

Now I want to add this in RichTextEditor using model or Looping, is it Possible on view page in Editor Control code.

Please suggest me some demo code or some Idea, and how to display all defined Fields in Drop down in Tool Bar, there is Winform Demo they have show but in MVC there is such kind of Feature is there?

Regards,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find a solution.
need to add a forloop and pass a list of token in model and add it 
rich text editor function by this all merge fields are generated and disply.

Comment: You want to post your solution?